# Regular expression for allowing certain sets of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of strings like this:

> Good Day,I would like to inquire the price of the **3D** product name here. Currently we have the other product name here which I believe has an accuracy of about **0.0005** **199 200**

I'm trying to create a regex for allowing `3D` to pass the filter, but remove things like `0.0005`, `199`, and `200`.

I am playing around with the regex but cannot find something to remove these without affecting `3D` in some way.

I have `/\W|\d+$/` so far.

Comment: *I am playing around with the regex* - could you share  what you have? Also, please check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `\W|\d+$` is what I have so far.

Comment: What you need, is: `replacedString = yourString.replace(/[0-9\s\.]+$/,"")`

Comment: Adam if you can answer as that, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Does it mean you want to remove any float and integer numbers at the end of the string only?

Comment: I've sent it as an answer as well.

Comment: They could appear anywhere in the string.

Comment: Then, you can use [`/\s*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew looks like the whitespace selector isn't really working throughout the whole string? I'm trying to incorporate non alphanumberic selectors in that regex as well to no avail. `\W*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b` is what I'd like, but it's not affecting it.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *working throughout the whole string*. If you also have punctuation, special symbols next to the numbers, you can add `\W*` instead of `\s*`, and perhaps, replace with a space. BTW, can you have numbers like `-.006` or `.05`?

Comment: Yeah I did that, `\W*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b` doens't have any affect on the string in your regex tester.

Comment: I added the link here: https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/2

Comment: But it matches `$1000` with a space before it. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Yeah but on this https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/3 there are remnant parenthesis and brackets, and dollar signs laying around. I thought `\W` would match those

Comment: Aha, you want to remove all non-whitespace and non-word characters. Try [`[^\w\s]|\W*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/4). You can extend it to keep punctuation: [`[^\w\s,.:;?!-]|\W*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/5). Or use an opposite approach: [`[$()[\]]|\W*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yE4kW6/6).

Comment: Ok, if you wish to stop here, mark Adam's answer as accepted. Then, rethink about the requirements, test, and come back with another, more precise, concrete question.

Answer (score 0):

```
"asdasd 3D sdfsdf 10.2213 sdfsf 1023 sdfsdfsdf 234".replace(/\b[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*\b/g, '');
```

gives:

```
"asdasd 3D sdfsdf  sdfsf  sdfsdfsdf "
```

Comment: This is close, but it removes `3D` in the quote above :)

Comment: `replace(/\b[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*\b/g, '');`

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need, is:

1. If you want to remove numbers from the end of your string: `string.replace(/[0-9\s\.]+$/,'')`
2. Or if you want to remove all the numbers from the sting: `replace(/\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\b/g, '');`

Comment: [`/\b[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/rV3fM7/1) will also remove `1.` from `1. Intro`.